# Command Line method to backup using two Time Machine disks

Tags: terminal, time-machine, script, defaults

Does anyone know of a command line method to select the active Time Machine disk? I would like to alternate between two backup disks for redundancy. I would like this to be automated, presumably via cron, perhaps launchd.

There is an [AppleScript method](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080105135511764) to swap disks, but I am doing remote system administration and cannot rely on GUI scripting. I would presume there is sufficient control of Time Machine using the **defaults** command, but am not sure how to achieve this yet.

Comment: Update: Here is a solution for this on 10.7 Lion: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110906221223743

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The restore component of backing up like this has not yet been tested.

Get the ID of the attached drive

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine BackupAlias
```

Eject, plug in 2nd drive, make it the Time Machine drive with the GUI, repeat.

Write (rather than read) the ID:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine BackupAlias '<00000000 014e0002 ....>'
```

[source](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2009/01/20/automatically-switching-between-different-time-machine-disks.html) & thanks to Christian Stocker. Key comments from that post:

1. http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html "WARNING: The defaults command will be changed in an upcoming major release to only operate on preferences domains. General plist manipulation utilities will be folded into a different command-line program."
2. Also the property DestinationVolumeUUID should be set.

Comment: This is easier to do on 10.7 Lion: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110906221223743

Answer (score 1):

If your need is to have redundancy on Time Machine backups, an alternative is to maintain a clone of your Time Machine Volume. I use [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/superduper/superduperdescription.html) for that purpose.